# Cassandra didn't stop well on Centos

Tags: cassandra, centos

I'm working on Centos (CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611), and trying to use Cassandra (3.0.9). The installation was quite easy to follow, and so far so good. But when I start Cassandra (using `systemctl start cassandra`) the service is : 
"`active (exited)`" instead of "`active (running)`".

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status cassandra
● cassandra.service - SYSV: Starts and stops Cassandra
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-05-03 12:06:54 CEST; 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9337 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 03 12:06:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Starts and stops Cassandra...
May 03 12:06:54 localhost.localdomain su[9344]: (to cassandra) root on none
May 03 12:06:54 localhost.localdomain cassandra[9337]: Starting Cassandra: OK
May 03 12:06:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started SYSV: Starts and stops Cassandra.
```

I decided to restart the service, using `systemctl restart cassandra`, but there is a problem with the stop process :

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl restart cassandra
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status cassandra
● cassandra.service - SYSV: Starts and stops Cassandra
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-05-03 12:15:50 CEST; 32s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9478 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 9508 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 03 12:15:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: cassandra.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 03 12:15:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit cassandra.service entered failed state.
May 03 12:15:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: cassandra.service failed.
May 03 12:15:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Starts and stops Cassandra...
May 03 12:15:49 localhost.localdomain su[9515]: (to cassandra) root on none
May 03 12:15:50 localhost.localdomain cassandra[9508]: Starting Cassandra: OK
May 03 12:15:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started SYSV: Starts and stops Cassandra.
```

Do you have some idea to solve this problem ? Thank you :)

Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi ! Can you explain me what's wrong with my question please ? It's the first time, I have to learn !

Comment: Your question pattern looks like okay ! moreover you can checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -Thank You

Comment: Can you add Centos version and Cassandra version too please?

Comment: Done ! 7.3 for centos, 3.0.9 for cassandra

Comment: Is your `system.log` telling you anything?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the Cassandra logs. See /var/log/cassandra/system.log